# How can I center My parent div vertically inside the body tag

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div inside a body and I want it to be vertically align at center with all the other child divs.
If I am wrong in any of the points please let me know.

```html
<style>
  .container{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
  .parent div{height:100px; width:100px; background-color:yellow; margin:10px auto;}
</style>
<body class="container">
     <div class"parent">
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You *could* add a height to your body (***the flex element***) and calculate the extra margin added by browser `height: calc(100vh - 16px);`

Comment: Why do you assume that the margin is 16px?

Comment: What should happen if the height of the viewport is smaller the height of the `.parent` element?

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot `=` in `class="parent"`

```html
<style>
  .container{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
  .parent div{height:100px; width:100px; background-color:yellow; margin:10px auto;}
</style>
<body class="container">
     <div class="parent">
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: well that's  just a typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Add width and height to the body which is container and also add = to the class="parent":

```
  <style>
  .container{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:100%; height: 100vh;}
  .parent div{height:100px; width:100px; background-color:yellow; margin:10px auto;}
</style>
<body class="container">
     <div class="parent">
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
           <div></div>
     </div>
</body>
```